# key arrow navigation on ul li not on input form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add arrow key navigation for ul li item on my page using jquery, however on the same page there is a form with input text. Problem is the input text also catch the key arrow event. How to go about so only the ul li container catch these event, not others. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show us your code? Or at least the pertinent parts?

Comment: Have you tried the [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) attribute?

Comment: I'm using jcarousel (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html), and add some click to load replace image at another container, to simluate a simple gallery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myForm input:text").on("keyDown", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

That <strike>should</strike> might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be solvable with more discrete class names and or selectors. As ul/li are *not* input elements, I'm not really sure where/why the problem is happening.

Please use the built in code display manager, or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) when you want help w/ code.